# How can I delete all the records from a TClientDataset at once?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Is possible delete all the records from a `TClientDataset` at once?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you must use the [`EmptyDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.EmptyDataSet) procedure.

try this

```
 ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
 try
   ClientDataSet1.EmptyDataSet;
 finally
   ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
 end;
```

Comment: DisableControls / EnableControls are not needed in this case.

Comment: True but then the next question becomes: *"how do I speed up clearing a Clientdataset?"*